# How to populate data in spinner after loading from webservice using async task in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I want to fill data in android spinner after states array comes from webService. After progress dialog loaded it will display data in spinner.

Following is my code. I am getting error in doInBackground Method. I am getting proper webservice response. But i will not display data in spinner.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SpinnerExample extends Fragment {

    private static ProgressDialog pleaseWaitDialog;
    private static ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private View rootView;
    private Spinner state_spinner;
    private String[] statesArray;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, container, false);
        state_spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state_spinner);
        SoapAccessTask soapAccessTask = new SoapAccessTask();
        soapAccessTask.execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    private class SoapAccessTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // Pre execution actions
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading State List");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            statesArray = WebService.getStateList();
            return statesArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (statesArray != null) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, statesArray);
                stateAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                state_spinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
                pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                AlertDialogError.showMessage(getActivity(), "Server Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `WebService`? What error are you getting?

Comment: What does `getStateList()` return ??

Comment: Weservice is class where I parse JSON data and getStateList() is method, it will return array of states. I am getting error after progress dialog loaded and it will crash the application.